# Tensorflow insatallation in windows only cpu version

Tags: windows, tensorflow

How to install `Tensorflow==1.5.0` cpu only version in windows ?

Also,i am using `python 3.8.0` version `pip 20.0.2`.

When I try the command pip to install `tensorflow==1.5.0`, it shows the following error :

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.5.0 (from versions: none)
>
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.5.0

Comment: Tensorflow has no support for python 3.8.. use an older version..

Comment: i changed python to 3.5 version but this error remains the same what to do

Comment: try pip install tensorflow==1.15

Comment: thanks it works after changing python to 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3.7

For Windows download the wheel file from this [link](https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow_cpu-2.1.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl)

For other os and python version check it on [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#tensorflow-2-packages-are-available) page

Once you have the file, install it by running

```
pip install /files/tensorflow_cpu-2.1.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl --user
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.5-3.7 versions 62 bit needs to used.It helped me to clear this error